# SQLAlchemy relationship through 2 many-to-many tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'B'

    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'C'

    c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class AB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'A_B'

    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.a_id), primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(B.b_id), primary_key=True)


class BC(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'B_C'

    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(B.b_id), primary_key=True)
    c_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(C.c_id), primary_key=True)
```

What I want is to add a relationship between A and C using the many-to-many tables b_id as joiner column. I know I can do it using seconday and secondaryjoin when there is a relationship through one many-to-many table, but I have no idea how to do that with 2 many-to-many tables.

I want something like this:

```
class A(Base):
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    c_colletion = relationship(?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom secondary:

```
ab = AB.__table__
bc = BC.__table__
ac = select([ab.c.a_id, bc.c.c_id]).select_from(ab.join(bc, ab.c.b_id == bc.c.b_id))

A.c_collection = relationship("C", secondary=ac,
                              primaryjoin=A.a_id == ac.c.a_id,
                              secondaryjoin=ac.c.c_id == C.c_id)
```

Comment: I wonder if just `relationship("C", secondary=join(AB, BC, AB.b_id == BC.b_id))` would work (following [Composite "Secondary" Joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins)). Was trying it out, and it doesn't seem to fail right away.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Nice! That's definitely a lot simpler. But I do feel like that seems too magical and not quite obvious how/why it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!