# Define relationship through double belongs-to-many in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables: `Item`, `Shelve` and `Cabinet`.

A `Cabinet` has-many `Shelve`s and a `Shelve` has-many `Item`s:

```
Item
    id: int
    shelve_id: int

Shelve
    id: int
    cabinet_id: int

Cabinet:
    id: id
```

I am looking to make the convenient relationship of `Cabinet` to a list of `Item`s:

```
class Cabinet(DeclarativeBase):
    # ...
    items: Mapped[List["Item"]] = relationship()
```

However, this gives an error that no relationship between `Cabinet` and `Item` could be found. Which I can understand because the relationship is not obvious, and `Shelve` will act as a sort of join table.

*How can I accomplish this in SQLAlchemy?*

I was reading the docs on [relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html) but I'm not sure which applies. Do I need a secondary join?
Other questions I found involve a double many-to-many relation, which sounds different: [SQLAlchemy relationship through 2 many-to-many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987959/sqlalchemy-relationship-through-2-many-to-many-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it's as easy as adding `secondary="shelves"` to either relationship. The models in full with the relationship I'm looking for:

```
class Cabinet(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "cabinets"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    shelves: Mapped[List["Shelve"]] = relationship(back_populates="cabinet")

    # Also provide indirect association:
    items: Mapped[List["Item"]] = relationship(
        secondary="shelves",
        back_populates="cabinet",
        viewonly=True,  # Prevent SAWArning
    )


class Shelve(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "shelves"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    cabinet_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("cabinets.id"))

    items: Mapped[List["Item"]] = relationship(back_populates="shelve")
    cabinet: Mapped["Cabinet"] = relationship(back_populates="shelves")


class Item(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    shelve_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("shelves.id"))

    shelve: Mapped["Shelve"] = relationship(back_populates="items")

    # Also provide indirect association:
    cabinet: Mapped["Item"] = relationship(
        secondary="shelves",
        back_populates="items",
        viewonly=True,  # Prevent SAWArning
    )
```

I am still confused though because without the `viewonly=True` I get a warning from SA:

> SAWarning: relationship 'Cabinet.items' will copy column cabinet.id to
> column shelves.cabinet_id, which conflicts with relationship(s):
> 'Shelves.cabinet' (copies cabinets.id to shelves.cabinet_id),
> 'Cabinets.shelves' (copies cabinets.id to shelves.cabinet_id). If
> this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be
> linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to
> one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that
> foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign()
> annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written
> towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter
> 'overlaps="shelves,cabinet"' to the 'Cabinet.items' relationship.
> (Background on this warning at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/qzyx) (This
> warning originated from the `configure_mappers()` process, which was
> invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)

And I don't really understand why.